# Commit failed (details follow): Server sent access forbidden and 403 Access Denied on the repository in response to DELETE request

Tags: apache, svn, ubuntu-14.04

Apology for my week knowledge in svn. I am managing the Apache subversion svn server which is deployed in azure Ubuntu 14.04 VM. And on client side using the Tortoise client 1.8.8. I am facing the issue while deleting any directory or file from the repository. I thought of it is a permission issue but user can able to create, edit the file and commit the same without any issue. But for deletion and then committing the same is giving the error. Please help me out. For your better view I have enclosed the screen capture of the Tortoise client error. Issue:

Error while performing action: Commit failed (details follow): Server sent unexpected return value (403 Access Denied) in response to DELETE request

I am getting this error every time I try to commit

Update happen no issues not able to delete and commit anything what wrong...

Things I have done:
- I have given full 777 permission to repos for authenticated users.
- Also have checked the password and auth file for users password and authentication, that is also correct.
- And the same is working at my home. So, Is there any network or firewall rules which is creating issue?

Waiting for the resolution.

Comment: why is this question tagged git?

Comment: 1. You **must** show: a) part of SVN-related http.conf b) authz-file (if used) 2. Question is more for SU|SF audience, than for SO